# Have Drop Down read from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react render function that will render a pop-up menu. The user should be able to select from a dropdown menu inside the popup. Since the list of items to be selected are too long it is not possible to have them typed by hand (also maintaining an updated version will be a pain). I am thinking of having them read from a list, but it seems I am out of luck. Can anyone advise me on how to go about doing this?

```
render(){
//entities is obviously a long list
var entities=["a","b","c",...];
 return(
 <div id="someid">
    <Input type="select" onChange={this.props.filterSelect}>
     {entities.map(e=><option>e</option>)}
    </Input>

 </div>
 );
```

The problem is in the drop-down menu I do not get specific entities but only get the letter "e".I do think the problem is related to the scope of the arrow function and how the scope of each item (e) in the call back does not reach within the

```
<option></option>
```

tags, sadly I do not know how to take care of this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
render(){
var entities=["a","b","c"];
 return(
 <div id="someid">
    <Input type="select" onChange={this.props.filterSelect}>
     {entities.map(e=><option key={e}>{e}</option>)}
    </Input>

 </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is simply you are missing {} around your variable so try `{entities.map(e=><option>{e}</option>)}`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
    //entities is obviously a long list
    var entities = ["a", "b", "c", ...];
    return (
        <div id= "someid" >
            <Input type="select" onChange = { this.props.filterSelect } >
                {
                    entities.map(e => <option>{ e } < /option>)
                }
            < /Input>
        < /div>
    )
}
```